# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, spyder, pytorch

using pytorch and python on implementing a self driving car i am getting this error.

```
File "C:\Users\Ganesh Bhat\Desktop\AI\Self_Driving_Car\ai.py", line 86, in update
    self.memory.push((self.last_state,new_state,torch.LongTensor([int(self.last_action)])),torch.tensor([self.last_reward]))

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

[here is my code of update function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGC1S.png)

```
def update(self,reward, new_signal):
    new_state = torch.Tensor(new_signal).float().unsqueeze(0)        
    self.memory.push((self.last_state,new_state,torch.LongTensor([int(self.last_action)]),torch.tensor([self.last_reward])))        
    action = self.select_action(new_state)
    if len(self.memory.memory) > 100:
        batch_state, batch_next_state, batch_reward, batch_action = self.memory.sample(100) 
        self.learn(batch_state, batch_next_state, batch_reward, batch_action)
    self.last_action = action
    self.last_state = new_state
    self.last_reward = reward
    self.reward_window.append(reward)
    if len(self.reward_window)>1000:
        del self.reward_window[0]
    return action
```

Comment: What is the type of `self.memory`? Your code tries to call push with two arguments. You have a tuple `(last_state, new_state, last_action)` and then `last_reward`, outside of the tuple. If `self.memory` is a list, this will not work. Is it intentional or a bug in parentheses?